# Ultima fecha de revisión con mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla de revisiones de articulos. Ejemplo:

```
pk_revision   |   fk_articulo    |  ultima_revision    |   prox_revision
========================================================================
      1                2            2019-03-25 00:00:00   2019-06-26 00:00:00
      2                2            2019-06-26 00:00:00   2019-09-27 00:00:00
      3                2            2019-09-27 00:00:00   2019-12-28 00:00:00
      4                3            2019-02-07 00:00:00   2019-08-07 00:00:00
      5                3            2019-08-07 00:00:00   2020-02-07 00:00:00
      6                1            2019-06-14 00:00:00   2020-06-14 00:00:00
```

En mi consulta quiero que me salga como resultado la última revision de cada articulo, pero no me sale el resultado que espero.

```
select fk_articulo, ultima_revision from inv_revision group by fk_articulo order by ultima_revision desc
```

Mi consulta me devuelve la primera revision que tiene cada articulo pero no la última. ¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que te falta la función de agregacion `MAX`

```
select fk_articulo, MAX(ultima_revision) 
from inv_revision 
group by fk_articulo
```

Si además quieres que aparezcan los artículos que no tienen revisión (los que están en inv_articulo pero no en inv_revision) podemos hacer un UNION:

```
select fk_articulo as articulo, MAX(ultima_revision) as revision
from inv_revision 
group by fk_articulo
UNION ALL
select pk_articulo as articulo, null as revision
from inv_articulo
where pk_articulo not in (select fk_articulo from inv_revision)
```

Comment: ¿Cómo podria cambiar la sentencia para que salgan también articulos que no tienen ninguna revisión?

Comment: Entiendo que estos artículos no están en la tabla `inv_revision`, ¿O están pero con `ultima_revision` a null?. Si es el primer caso deberías hacer un UNION con la tabla de artículos ¿como se llama y que campos tiene?

Comment: Esos articulos no están en la tabla `inv_revision` porque no han tenido o no tienen revision. Osea, están en la tabla `inv_articulo`

Comment: Tiene como campos: `pk_articulo`, `nombre`, `referencia`, `fecha_alta`, `fecha_baja`

Comment: @Maginon, he ampliado la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el `group by` está demás. Esto te debe funcionar. Saludos!

```
select fk_articulo, ultima_revision 
from inv_revision 
order by ultima_revision desc;
```